# AS3 text field, truncation

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a text field that dynamically adjusts its width to fit the screen. I want the text to be truncated and appended with '...' if it it doesn't fit. But how do I know if the text value is longer than the available text field width?

Answer (score 9):

Hey what about going simple :-)

```
while ( textfield.numLines > MAX ) 
    textfield.text = textfield.text.slice(0, -4) + "...";
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Then the OP can set MAX to 1

Comment: Which wouldn't truncate the text at all, since there is no width checking in your loop..? Unless you mean setting both wordWrap/multiline to true before running your loop... Yes, that way it would work a treat :-)

Answer (score 2):

`yourTextField.textWidth` gives you the length of the TextField's text.
Just make sure to set the TextField's autosize property first, to really get the text's width and not the width of the TextField.

Answer (score 2):

I needed this exact same function, what I did was whenever a resize event was triggered that resulted in the `TextField` object needing to be resized I perform a little loop as follows:

```
tfMessage.text = message;

if(tfMessage.width > maximumWidth)
{
    tfMessage.appendText("...");

    while(tfMessage.width > maximumWidth)
    {
        tfMessage.text = tfMessage.text.substr(0, -4) + "...";
    }
}
```

Make sure the `TextField` object's `autoSize` property is set to `TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT` to make the object automatically resize whenever you update the text. You can use the other values in the `TextFieldAutoSize` enumeration but `LEFT` works best for me. Usage example:

```
tfMessage.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
```

It may seem like overkill but it's your best, cleanest option. Besides, I use this to resize hundreds of `TextField` objects fine with no performance degradation on an average computer. Give Flash some credit haha, they've done okay with the AVM2 tweaks and optimisations.

Anyway I hope this helps, works perfect for me. Good luck with your project.

Comment: This was April of last year, granted I feel I've improved since then. Kudos on your answer though, definitely the best suggested solution!

Answer (score 1):

probably the only way to do it is if the textWidth is longer than the width, to loop through the text letter by letter either adding or removing a letter at a time and adding the ellipsis and checking the width until it is close to filling the entire text field.

Comment: Could add some serious overhead if I'm looping this over over a list of say 100 text fields? mmm

Comment: yes, but how else would you do it? You can set up a minimum and maximum number of characters, so that if you're over or under the buffer, it kicks in, saving you some loops.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after some brain racking, I thought how about leaving the string to crop in the textField, and simply adding an extra "..." in a new MC and setting its visiblity to false. When the textField.textWidth >= textField.width it makes the "..." MC visible and positions it at the end of the textField. This could be inside or outside of the textField.